# JSON logs are not wrapped properly in Splunk website when syntax highlighting is enabled

Tags: splunk

My company uses Splunk website for saving the logs.

I have the following setting in my Splunk:
[image]

Raw text from Splunk:

```
{"cf_app_id":"uuid","cf_app_name":"app-name","deployment":"cf","event_type":"LogMessage","info_splunk_index":"splunk-index","ip":"ipaddr","message_type":"OUT","msg":"2022-12-22 19:11:30.242 DEBUG [app-name,02c11142eee3be456dc30ddb1b234d5f,f20222ba46461ea9] 28 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] classname    : {\"data\":{\"fields\":[{\"__typename\":\"name\",\"field\":\"value\",\"field2\":\"value2\",\"field3\":\"value 3\",\"field4\":\"value4\",\"field5\":\"value5\",\"field6\":\"value6\",\"field7\":\"value7\",\"field8\":null,\"field9\":\"value9\",\"field10\":null,\"field11\":111059.0,\"field12\":111059.0,\"field13\":null,\"field14\":\"value14\",\"field15\":\"2018-10-01\",\"field16\":null,\"field17\":false,\"field18\":{\"field19\":\"value19\",\"fieldl20\":\"value20\",\"field21\":2.6,\"field22\":\"2031-10-31\",\"field23\":\"2017-11-06\"},\"field24\":{\"field25\":\"\",\"field26\":\"\"},\"field27\":{\"field28\":{\"field29\":0.0,\"field30\":0.0,\"field31\":240.63,\"field32\":\"2022-12-31\",\"field33\":0.0,\"field34\":\"9999-10-31\"}},\"field35\":[{\"field36\":{\"field37\":\"value37\"}},{\"field38\":{\"field39\":\"value39\"}}],\"field40\":{\"__typename\":\"value40\",\"field41\":\"value41\",\"field42\":\"value 42\",\"field43\":111059.0,\"field44\":\"2031-04-01\",\"field45\":65204.67,\"field46\":null,\"field47\":\"value47\",\"field48\":\"value48\",\"field49\":null,\"field50\":\"value50\",\"field51\":null,\"field52\":null}},{\"__typename\":\"value53\",\"field54\":\"value54\",\"field55\":\"value55\",\"field56\":\"value56\",\"field57\":\"value57\",\"field58\":\"value58\",\"field59\":\"9\",\"field60\":\"value60\",\"field61\":null,\"field62\":\"value62\",\"field63\":null,\"field64\":88841.0,\"field65\":38841.0,\"field66\":null,\"field67\":\"value67\",\"field68\":\"2018-10-01\",\"field69\":null,\"field70\":false,\"field71\":{\"field72\":\"value72\",\"field73\":\"value73\",\"field74\":2.6,\"field75\":\"2031-10-31\",\"field76\":\"2017-11-06\"},\"field77\":{\"field78\":\"\",\"field79\":\"\"},\"field80\":{\"field81\":{\"field82\":0.0,\"field83\":0.0,\"field84\":84.16,\"field85\":\"2022-12-31\",\"field86\":0.0,\"field87\":\"9999-10-31\"}},\"field88\":[{\"field89\":{\"field90\":\"value90\"}},{\"field91\":{\"field92\":\"value92\"}}],\"field93\":null},{\"__typename\":\"value94\",\"field95\":\"value95\",\"field96\":\"value96\",\"field97\":\"value97\",\"field98\":\"value98\",\"field99\":\"value99\",\"field100\":\"1\",\"field101\":\"value101\",\"field102\":null,\"field103\":\"value103\",\"field104\":\"359\",\"field105\":88025.0,\"field106\":79316.87,\"field107\":\"309\",\"field108\":\"value108\",\"field109\":\"2018-10-01\",\"field110\":\"2048-09-30\",\"field111\":false,\"field112\":{\"field113\":\"value113\",\"field114\":\"value114\",\"field115\":2.35,\"field116\":\"2031-10-31\",\"field117\":\"2017-11-06\"},\"field118\":{\"field119\":\"\",\"field120\":\"\"},\"field121\":{\"field122\":{\"field123\":341.58,\"field124\":0.0,\"field125\":155.33,\"field126\":\"2022-12-31\",\"field127\":186.25,\"field128\":\"2022-12-31\"}},\"field129\":[{\"field130\":{\"field131\":\"value131\"}},{\"field132\":{\"field133\":\"value133\"}}],\"field134\":null}]}}","origin":"rep","source_instance":"0","source_type":"APP/PROC/WEB","timestamp":1671732690243306564}
```

But this JSON message is not wrapped completely i.e I still see horizontal scroll bar in the browser even though I enabled wrapping of search results in Splunk website. If I search for different search results without the big nested JSON in `msg` field then those messages are wrapped properly:
[image]

How can I fix this in Splunk website? FYI, I only have a "user" role in Splunk

can I specify something in Splunk search query to solve this?

Comment: My application uses slf4j for logs. Since Splunk is not wrapping JSON log properly, is there something I can mention in properties file so that slf4j "wraps without new line" before logging

Comment: https://community.splunk.com/t5/Splunk-Search/Why-doesn-t-quot-Wrap-results-quot-fit-to-the-screen-or-is-there/m-p/429099

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74894433/transform-splunk-json-event/74895152#74895152

Comment: https://community.splunk.com/t5/Splunk-Search/Why-doesn-t-quot-Wrap-results-quot-fit-to-the-screen-or-is-there/m-p/625195

Answer (score 0):

Temporary workaround:-
I see that some big messages are not wrapped correctly which is causing this issue in `List` view. Every Splunk event in my case is a JSON(with fields like cf_app_name, etc) and when there is also a large JSON or text inside the `msg` field then the value is not wrapped properly causing the horizontal scrolling issue.

Also, when viewing the logs I only need the `msg` field as I am not interested in the other fields of the Splunk JSON event.

So my fix is to query in Splunk with the command `app_name=app-name msg=* | spath msg | eval _raw="{\"msg\":\""+msg+"\"}"` and in `eval` I will dynamically make the JSONs as invalid structure if they are too big. Then the events which have large text will not have syntax highlighting as they are probably not valid JSON(due to not properly escaping the quotes etc). This is fine because horizontal scrollbar is too annoying compared to loosing syntax highlighting for only a few big messages

FYI, If I escape the big JSON messages to get the syntax highlighting working then I will probably be back to square one where the horizontal scrollbar will be back again

So I have no option but to use this temporary fix until Splunk company fixes their website to wrap big nested JSON/text properly in `List` view

Comment: I do not use `Raw` view because then I loose syntax highlighting for all messages and not just for few big messages