# Transform Splunk JSON event

Tags: splunk

I have the below JSON event in Splunk.

```
{
    "cf_app_id": "uuid",
    "cf_app_name": "app-name",
    "deployment": "cf",
    "event_type": "LogMessage",
    "info_splunk_index": "splunk-index",
    "ip": "ipaddr",
    "message_type": "OUT",
    "msg": "2022-12-22 19:11:30.242 DEBUG [app-name,02c11142eee3be456dc30ddb1b234d5f,f20222ba46461ea9] 28 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] classname    : This is the log message",
    "origin": "rep",
    "source_instance": "0",
    "source_type": "APP/PROC/WEB",
    "timestamp": 1671732690242714069
}
```

Now when I get the search results then I want it to be displayed like this:

```
{
    "msg": "2022-12-22 19:11:30.242 DEBUG [app-name,02c11142eee3be456dc30ddb1b234d5f,f20222ba46461ea9] 28 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] classname    : This is the log message"
}
```

How do I achieve this in Splunk SPL command?

I tried this command which did not work
`searchquery | eval _raw="{\"msg\":\""+_raw.msg+"\"}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is very close, but before one can reference the msg field, it first must be parsed.

```
<<search query>>
| spath 
| eval _raw="{\"msg\": \"" . msg . "\"}"
```

Comment: I see empty event in Splunk

Comment: got it working. `search query | spath msg
| eval _raw="{\"msg\":\""+msg+"\"}"`